# Create a VCL Button Component with sound

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I'm trying to create a custom VCL component that can have a custom sound played when clicked. The sound is accessed from a resource DLL.

Question is, the sound is played using Direct X, and for it to be created it need a valid window handle.

My naive initial test was to initialize the sound in the components constructor:

```
__fastcall TArrayBotButton::TArrayBotButton(TComponent* Owner)
    : TBitBtn(Owner),
    FSoundID("BUTTON_CLICK_1")
{
initABCoreLib();
HWND hWnd = Application->MainFormHandle;
mSound.Create(FSoundID.c_str(), hWnd);
}
```

but the above does not work, as the MainFormHandle at this point is NULL. Also, being a component, using the Application variable is probably not safe in the constructor(?).

Any pointers on where to initialize the sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the button's own `HWND` instead? `TBitBtn` is a windowed control. Its `HWND` is not available in the constructor, but you can (and should) override the button's virtual `CreateWnd()` method to create the DirectX object, and override the virtual `DestroyWnd()` method to release it. This way you also account for window recreations during the button's lifetime.

Comment: Worked perfect, and made everything much simpler.